# When adding new endpoints to my net6 API on Azure App Service slot, I receive 404 not found ONLY on the new endpoints

Tags: .net-6.0, azure-appservice

I have an API that has lots of controllers and endpoints. It was built on `net 3.1` and was **recently migrated to** `net 6`. The migration worked fine.

Let's say that this API has one controller called `ProductController`, and this controller have a bunch of endpoints. One of them we can call it `GetProductsByUserAndType`.
I had to create a new endpoint, inside this existing controller, called `GetProductsByUser`.

- I run my api locally and the new endpoint works fine.
- I publish it on an appservice hosted in a testing environment and it works fine
- I publish it in release mode in a folder, run the .exe file and it works fine

But when I publish it in on an **appservice-slot** hosted in a production environment, this new endpoint throws a `404 not found`.

I recently added a **new Controller** to this API **with a new endpoint**, and this new endpoint also throws `404 not found`.

I'm really lost here because this problem doesn't make sense to me. Why come only new endpoints doesn't work ? I have 2 endpoints living side-by-side on a controller and one of them throws 404 (the new one) and the other not.

---

I tried to:

- search for the problem: I found nothing related, this situation looks very specific;
- re-deploy the code to the appservice-slot (I use the Local git option);
- deploy using the Publish configuration on Visual Studio 2022;

Answer (score 0):

As I was writing this question, a teamate suggested to **delete the slot** and **create a new one.**

I did that, deployed again and it worked. So, I hope this helps someone out there.